# Enumerate all objects in QQmlEngine

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2, metaclass

I want to enumerate all the objects (derived from `QObject`) existent and newly created in `QQmlApplicationEngine`. The main goal it to execute the following lines of code for each of them:

```
void denominate(QObject * const object)
{
    if (object->objectName().isEmpty()) {
        object->setObjectName(object->metaObject()->className());
    }
}
```

It is needed to distinct some of the objects in QML runtime. Say, when `StackView` items are created from `Component`s and I want to know which of them is really on the top.

Creation of some of components or C++ classes are delayed. And if I get a root objects and enumerate `children()` of them, it is a half of the solution. Also there is `QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated` signal, but I don't fully understand interrelation between contexts, engine and (root) objects.

How to name all the unnamed objects, which lives into `QQmlEngine`?

Comment: Note, that `typeof` always returns "object".

Comment: You can call custom signal from QML in the Component.OnCompleted method, and send QObject as a parameter.

Comment: @arturx64 For all the objects? No. Surely I can, but I don't want. There is an object tree in Qt (and QML) and I just want to traverse it.

Comment: @arturx64 There is even simplier method: to set `objectName` property of interesting objects only. But this is also error prone approach. What if I miss to initialize this property for some of objects of interest?

Comment: You have to work only with appeared object. Theoretically, you need visible property of QML item. Try to make connection to OnVisibleChanged, signal or another signals while you enumerate all objects.

Comment: @arturx64 But the question is "how to enumerate". I can't understand your suggestions.

Comment: Try to enumerate all object in the QML use childItems method of QQuickItem. https://forum.qt.io/topic/43334/solved-iterate-through-children-of-a-qml-item/3

Comment: @arturx64 I have no one `QQuickItem`. Linked code is not C++.

Comment: It is base class for all visual components. When you create QML element from c++ side the QQuickItem* pointer is used like this: QQmlComponent component(m_qmlEngine, QUrl(qmlPath)); QQuickItem* item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(omponent.create());

Answer (score 2):

You can rename all of them using recursive enumeration
For example:
QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
   visible: true
   width: 640
   height: 480
   title: qsTr("Hello World")

MouseArea
{
    id: r1
    width: 200
    height: 200
}

Rectangle
{
    id: r2
    color: "green"
    width: 100
    height: 100
    Item
    {
        id: r3
        width: 50
        height: 50
    }
}
}
```

You can set their names in the c++ part using the next mechanism:

```
 void changeNames(QList<QObject*> ch)
 {
    for( QObject* ob: ch)
    {
        if (ob->objectName().isEmpty())
        {
            ob->setObjectName(ob->metaObject()->className());
        }
        changeNames( ob->children() );
    }
}

void enumerate(QList<QObject*> ch)
{
    for( QObject* ob: ch)
    {
        qInfo() << ob->objectName();
        enumerate( ob->children() );
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();

    changeNames(rootObject->children());
    enumerate(rootObject->children());

    return app.exec();
}
```

You will see the next names in the output:
"QQuickRectangle"
"QQuickMouseArea"
"QQuickItem"

If you have to add new component dynamically you can repeat this procedure, or find necessary component and rename it

Comment: What if not me? How to catch all the events?

Comment: If you want to catch all events you can use event filter http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html